# How can I aggregate boolean values within a column to give sum of trues and false?

Tags: sql, sum, boolean, aggregate, teradata

So I have a table Output in the form of :

| COlA. | ColB. | ColC. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T. | F. | T |
| F | T | F |
| F | T | F |

I want to sum the number of Trues and False by column to give me :

| . | True_Sum | False_Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COlA | 1 | 2 |
| ColB | 2 | 1 |
| ColC | 1 | 2 |

Could someone please help me understand how I would query this?
Thank you in advance!

I tried using case when statements :

select colA, colB, colC,
sum (case when ColA = 'T' or ColB = 'T'or ColC = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as True_Sum,
sum (case when ColA = 'F' or ColB = 'F'or ColC = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as False_Sum
from Output
group by 1,2,3

Obviously this is not correct. I struggle with aggregates!

Comment: You probably want to format your tables because it is definitely not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Yes sorry just realised - formatted now! thanks

Comment: Looks like what you need is a pivot, here are the docs: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2019/Aggregate-Functions/PIVOT/Examples/Example-Alias-Names-Contained-in-the-IN-List

Answer (score 0):

If it's as simplistic as your example is (just a few columns), I'd just aggregate each and union them together.  I'm far too lazy to figure out pivoting and unpivoting if I don't have to.

```
select
cast('colA' as varchar(100)), --make sure this can handle you longest column name
sum(case when colA = 'T'  then 1 else 0 end)  true_sum,
sum(case when colA = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as false_sum
from 
<your table>

UNION ALL
select
'colB',
sum(case when colB = 'T'  then 1 else 0 end)  true_sum,
sum(case when colB = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as false_sum
from 
<your table>

UNION ALL
select
'colC',
sum(case when colC = 'T'  then 1 else 0 end)  true_sum,
sum(case when colC = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as false_sum
from 
<your table>
```